# How can I make output table results in R appear in more aesthitically pleasing format?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, visualization

I have come across someone else's notebook on kaggle and for same code (`skimr::skim(df_churn)`) his output looks so better than mine aesthetically.

Below pic is the comparison.

Left is my Rmarkdown editor & on right is the kaggle notebook output.

[image]

His output has really good readability and mine looks raw and difficult to read.

**How can I achieve similar results - is there a package** for that ?

(I am  a newbie in programming / R)

I have even tried to implement this on kaggle cloud to make sure if notebook on kaggle is making any changes or not but it's not.

Link to kaggle source (https://www.kaggle.com/ar89dsl/exploring-tidymodels)

Comment: Try the gt package (https://gt.rstudio.com/). Other options at https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/

Comment: Use R Markdown, and see the help page for `knitr::knit_print`.

Comment: Thanks @mrhellmann and user2554330 for the suggestions. 
I think the link mentioned by mrhellmann has some useful options that I am looking for.